# How do I get the full path for a filename command-line argument?

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos

I've found lots of libraries to help with parsing command-line arguments, but none of them seem to deal with handling filenames. If I receive something like "../foo" on the command line, how do I figure out the full path to the file?

Comment: Why do you think you need the full path to the file? Syscalls work just fine with relative paths.

Comment: I believe the command 'pwd' gives you your current path/location. You should be able to figure the rest... but Andrew (comment above) is correct.

Comment: My utility generates some text files so I need the complete path. Constructing paths sounds like a pain, this must have been solved a 1000 times already.

Comment: pass the utility the full path. Problem solved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

POSIX has [`realpath()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/realpath.html).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *realpath(const char *filename, char *resolvedname);
```

**DESCRIPTION**
The *realpath()* function derives, from the pathname pointed to by *filename*, an absolute pathname that names the same file, whose resolution does not involve ".", "..", or symbolic links. The generated pathname is stored, up to a maximum of {PATH_MAX} bytes, in the buffer pointed to by *resolvedname*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Jonathan; and especially for the summary.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `boost::filesystem` to get the `absolute path` of a file, from its `relative path`:

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
fs::path p("test.txt");
fs::path full_p = fs::complete(p); // complete == absolute
std::cout << "The absolute path: " << full_p;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 1):

In shell scripts, the command "readlink -f" has the functionality of realpath().